# How to evaluate $\int{d(y^2)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Can anybody help me to solve this integral please:  $$\int{dy^2}$$

Here $dy^2$ means $d(y^2)$, not $(dy)^2$.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hint: You know that $\int dx = x + c$. Now put $x=y^2$. Alternatively: $dy^2 = 2y dy$ what does $\int 2y dy$ equals?

Comment: Is $d(y^2)$ meant.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming indefinite integration:
$$
u = y^2 \Rightarrow \\
\int dy^2 = \int du = u + C = y^2 + C
$$

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to solve here. You want to know what happens when you differentiate and integrate $y^2$...  you get back same $y^2$, but added with an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 0):

Two methods:
$$\int dx=x+c\implies \int dy^2=y^2+c\\
\mathrm{OR}\\
\int dy^2=\int 2ydy=2\int ydy=2\left(\dfrac{1}{2}y^2+C\right)=y^2+2C=y^2+c$$